# Generic method - parameter type casting

Tags: c#

I heve been looking for solution of my problem for many hours with no clear answers so I am forced to ask here.
Here is my sample code:

```
class Geometry
{
    public static Vector2 quadraticCurvePoint(Vector2 _p1, Vector2 _p2, Vector2 _p3, float _t)
    {
        return (1 - _t) * (1 - _t) * _p1 + 2 * (1 - _t) * _t * _p2 + _t * _t * _p3;
    }

    public static Vector3 quadraticCurvePoint(Vector3 _p1, Vector3 _p2, Vector3 _p3, float _t)
    {
        return (1 - _t) * (1 - _t) * _p1 + 2 * (1 - _t) * _t * _p2 + _t * _t * _p3;
    }

    public static T[] quadraticCurve<T>(T _p1, T _p2, T _p3, uint _q)
    {
        int points_count = (int)_q + 2;
        T[] points = new T[points_count];
        points[0] = _p1;
        points[points_count - 1] = _p3;
        float ti = 1 / points_count;
        float t;
        for (int i = 1; i <= _q; i++)
        {
            t = ti * i;
            points[i] = quadraticCurvePoint(_p1, _p2, _p3, t);
        }
        return points;
    }
}
```

I want to pass only types Vector2 and Vector3 but I don't have any idea how to make this call `points[i] = quadraticCurvePoint(_p1, _p2, _p3, t);` working becouse program does not know what type is _p1 _p2 _p3.

Vector2 and Vector3 are part of OpenTK project. They are declared as `public struct Vector2 : IEquatable<Vector2>` and have operators implementations.

Of course I can simply write overloaded version of this method (duplicate code) for Vector2 and Vector3 but I it's not in BADASS programmer style.

I know I have already overloaded quadraticCurvePoint method buts it will be improved in the same way as the quadraticCurve method - if possible...

Comment: sadly you cannot really use generics over operations - not in C# (you cannot get static operations into interface to constraints generic type parameters) so you either have to use two overloads (I would do) or use some nasty reflection/dynamics stuff

Comment: I suppose the "nasty reflection/dynamics" are not worth of implementing due to performance decrease. Thank You for Your time.

Answer (score 0):

Using generics in C# is completely different than in C++, the compiler won't try to "guess" what you mean, you need to explicitely tell it. This is beceause in C# generics are not just templates for classes, being specified on compilation. They are real types.

Best you can to is to use generic parameter constraints: https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/d5x73970.aspx